# SQL - Omitting/Hide Specific Search Values

Tags: sql, hide, infomaker

I've been having an issue with reports at work lately that we need to pull data but omit a specific sport type from the results. We still need the names and other information to pull, just not a specific sport.

We have the report showing:

```
'Student' 'Address' 'Major' 'Hockey'
'Student' 'Address' 'Major' 'BSKB'
'Student' 'Address' 'Major' 'VLB'
```

But we need it to read:

```
'Student' 'Address' 'Major' 
'Student' 'Address' 'Major' 'BSKB'
'Student' 'Address' 'Major' 'VLB'
```

Is this actually something that can be done? My boss swears by it, but I feel that my classes told me it couldn't. It's a basic Select Query that we use, just with some in depth "Cases" to pull students based on major.

Thank you for any input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just guessing at the field names. Hope you understand the general idea:

```
SELECT student, address, major,
    CASE sporttype
    WHEN 'Hockey' THEN Null
    ELSE sporttype END AS sporttype
FROM sporttable
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That makes sense to me. I'll go ahead and give it a try.

Comment: Depending on the size of the table query could you also use an IIF statement instead of a CASE statement.   `SELECT student, address, major, IIF(Sporttype = "Hockey", Null, Sporttype) from sporttable`

Comment: The case ended up half working. I'm able to have the 'Hockey" disappear but none of the other sports will populate now.

(Case when 'sport column' = 'HOCKE' then Null Else 'sport column' End) As 'sport column'

Comment: We did it! Thank you both so much for your help.

Comment: @JacobKleiman I'm glad you got it working now. I guess you figured out you had too many apostrophes at first try. If my answer was of any help to you, you can select it as a solution to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want using the ROLAP 'datacube' operator

```
SELECT student, address, major,type
from table
group by cube (student, address, major, type)
having grouping(student)=0 and grouping(address)=0 and grouping(major)=0
```